# Create Custom API V8 in Suite CRM

Tags: suitecrm

Good Day!

I am planning to create a custom API for Account module were I am going to get and update data using API. I created a custom field (**integration_ref_id**) on my Account module this will serve as my identifier if the accounts is existing or not. ***Check bellow as payload request sample***

```
{
"consent_timestamp": "2021-04-13 09:45:00",
"integration_ref_id": "CUSREF-202104-ABCDEF0000003",
"last_name": "De la Cruz",
"first_name": "Juan",
"birthdate": "1995-03-25",
"mobile_number": "+639171234199",
"email": "juan.delacruz@example.com",
"location_code": "LOC0001",
"street_name": "Rose St.",
"landmarks": "Mcdo",
"gender": "male"
}
```

Now I created custom routes on my custom folder (**custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/Config**)

```
<?php
$app->get('/my-route/{myParam}', 'MyCustomController:myCustomAction');

$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello World!';
});

$app->get('/getCustomers', 'Api\V8\Controllers\CustomersController:getCustomers');
```

And I place the controller same path of the routes. (**custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/Controller**)

And this is my controller code

```
<?php
namespace Api\V8\Controller;

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) {
    die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
}



class CustomersController extends BaseController
{
    public function getCustomers(Request $request, Response $response, array $args, GetRelationshipParams $params)
    {
        try {
            $jsonResponse = $this->relationshipService->getCustomers($request);
            return $this->generateResponse($response, $jsonResponse, 200);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return $this->generateErrorResponse($response, $exception, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this Error in postman
[image]

I keep searching, but its kinda confusing on my end. BTW I am new on this SuiteCRM

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I was able to figure it out. I just added this code below to my controller **CustomeController.php**

```
namespace Api\V8\Controller;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Slim\Http\Request;
```

And added this one to my custom **controller.php**

```
require 'custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/Controller/CustomersController.php';
use Api\V8\Controller;
use Slim\Container;
```

Then everything should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the newest version 8.4 installed. I created a custom module and can successfully pull the info from the module using the API get method. I understand that to post a new record in the module, I would need to customize the API as documented Here. However, the referenced file Extending Slim configuration custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/slim.php or, as I assume, public/legacy/custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/slim.php does not exist.

Your post leads me to believe that I am to create a file in /public/legacy**/cu**stom/application/Ext/Api/V8/Config/; however, I am unclear what the file name should be and if that is indeed the correct location.

Furthermore, would the custom/application/Ext/Api/V8/Controller location actually be public/legacy/Api/V8/Controller ? Or is it another location file name that needs to be referenced somewhere or extend something?

Comment: Nevermind, I did not need to create a custom endpoint. The solution is to use {baseurl}/ module/ 

With a body of
{
  "data": {
    "type": "{module name}",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Test account"
    }
  }
  }